# dynamic creation of php code from array in php

Tags: php, dynamic, code-generation

I have a code to generate php code from an array of words, however the list of words is variable
like:

```
    $list=array(
    "BMW",
    "MUSTANG",
    "DBM",
    "Txt62"
    );

$arrlength=count($list);

for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
  {
  echo ' \'' .$list[$x]. '\'' . ' => $this->input->post("'.$list[$x].'") == \'\' ? \'Not defined definido\' : $this->input->post("'.$list[$x].'"),  ';
  echo "<br>";
  }
```

Is there a better way to do it, like a function that I pass the array of words, and it returns php code?, Is this possible inside php code?

Comment: https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHPPHP

Comment: Not sure what's the problem ?

Comment: from an array of words, I want to generate php code for each of  those  words, the problem is, I can not make dynamic php code..}

Comment: @cMinor ok, you want a new .php file, what does that PHP file do ?

Comment: It catches post values from all fields given a table in MYsql, then generates a code to validate all of the fields

Comment: Are you trying to validate the post inputs in CodeIgniter ?

Comment: Exactly you figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to understand what you're trying to do, but if it is to run a function on every item in an array, you can use array_walk for that ?

```
$list = array(
              "BMW",
              "MUSTANG",
              "DBM",
              "Txt62"
             );

function validate($item, $key) {
    echo ' \'' .$item. '\'' . ' => $this->input->post("'.$item.'") == \'\' ? \'Not defined definido\' : $this->input->post("'.$item.'"),  <br>';
}

array_walk($list, 'validate');
```